# package ‘tidyverse’ is not available

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to install "tidyverse" and I get the below error.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")

package ‘tidyverse’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tidyverse’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)
```

The below is details about my Session.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12.1 (unknown)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.3
```

Would anyone have any idea what's missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you try:

```
install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, type="source")
```

You may also want to try to update the version of R you are using.

Comment: Definitely update R if you can. `tidyverse` has only been available for a few months, R version 3.1.3 is 2 years old.

Comment: When I click on the 'check updates' under help it say's "you're using the latest version of Rstdio"

Comment: The latest R version is 3.3.3, you might want to update that.

Comment: @uut - when I install tidyverse with the command - > install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=TRUE, type="source"), I am getting the below error - Installing package into '/home/nbcommon/R'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning message:
"package 'tidyverse' is not available (for R version 3.3.0)"[Note: I am using Microsoft azure jupyter notebook] Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: @ksp585 I'm not exactly sure what is going on, but you could try `install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, type="source", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")` .

Answer (score 2):

if you are using ubuntu try this and then install tidyverse again

> ## Required for many packages
>
> sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev